# Multipe exec.Command function with pipelines does not give a output in Golang

Tags: linux, go, exec

I'm trying to execute program in golang and catch output of the second program to pass web output.
Single execution is does not cause any problem ,

```golang
//One exec
        t := time.Now()
        filename := "backup-" + hostname + "-" + t.Format(time.RFC3339) + ".img"
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename)
        // Set HTTP header befare Transfering data.
        w.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")

        ddCommand := exec.Command("dd", fmt.Sprintf("if=%s", r.URL.Path[6:]))
        pipeIn, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()
        ddCommand.Stdout = pipeWriter
        ddCommand.Stderr = pipeWriter

        go writeCmdOutput(w, pipeIn)

        ddCommand.Run()
        pipeWriter.Close()
```

but when I added second program to function, program does not give any output.

```golang
                // Get time and set headers
                t := time.Now()
                filename := "backup-" + hostname + "-" + t.Format(time.RFC3339) + ".img.gz"
                w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename)
                w.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")

                pipeIn, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()

                ddCommand := exec.Command("dd", fmt.Sprintf("if=%s", r.URL.Path[9:]))
                gzipCommand := exec.Command("gzip ", "-1", "-")


                gzipCommand.Stdin, _ = ddCommand.StdoutPipe()

                gzipCommand.Stdout = pipeWriter
                go writeCmdOutput(w, pipeIn)

                _ = gzipCommand.Start()
                _ = ddCommand.Run()
                _ = gzipCommand.Wait()
                pipeWriter.Close()
```

But when I try to run command without pipeline the execution gives a realtime output. Example command

```golang
topCommand := exec.Command("top","-d 0.5", "-b", "-n 5")
awkCommand   := exec.Command("grep", "bash")

awkCommand.Stdin, _ = topCommand.StdoutPipe()
awkCommand.Stdout = os.Stdout

_ = awkCommand.Start()
_ = topCommand.Run()
_ = awkCommand.Wait()
```

So how can I fix this issue ?
For more details [project source](https://github.com/AhmetOZER/dibow/blob/alpha/server/web_server.go)

Comment: This from the docs for StdoutPipe might explain the problem: "Wait will close the pipe after seeing the command exit, so most callers need not close the pipe themselves. It is thus incorrect to call Wait before all reads from the pipe have completed. "

Comment: Try using `os.Pipe`, not `io.Pipe`, so that the the file descriptor can be passed directly to the process.

Comment: replacing io.Pipe with os.Pipe is does not change anything, result is same. @JimB